How to structure multivariate timeseries when timeseries metadata varies
I am forecasting from multivariate, geographical timeseries.
My data includes historical prices and production quantities per product, and different places produce and sell different sets of products. For example:



San Francisco
Month 1
Month 2
Month 3




Wheat





Price USD
3
4
3


Qty Produced T
200
100
150


Apples





Price USD
1
2
0.8


Qty Produced T
20
10
50






Brisbane
Month 1
Month 2
Month 3




Rice





Price USD
3
4
3


Qty Produced T
200
100
150


Banana





Price USD
5
4
3


Qty Produced T
200
300
450



The product lists are different for each location (as are date ranges and lengths, but solutions for these issues are well documented). I'm looking to detect anomalies and forecast a consumption category. How should I structure this for training and forecasting?

My Guesses (you can probably stop reading here as this is novice guesswork, but SO recommends including work done so far):
One approach I could use would be to normalize and average all prices. (Prices are collected for the most important products in each area.) This would remove a lot of detail though. I could guess how important each product is by the quantity grown, but this will often be misleading. The relationships and tensions between price and production are important.
I guess the brute force approach would be to have every product in every example, with an empty token for any products' timeseries not traded in an area. That would be a very sparse and large dataset though.
Could I have say product1="rice w2v embedding", product2="banana w2v embedding", price_timeseries1=[rice prices], price_timeseries2=[banana prices] (plus production, and in another example, same for wheat and apples)? Is any model going to make sense of that?
My best guess is categorizing products, eg, into 'carbohydrate' for rice and wheat, and normalize then mean average the products of each category. (I do have a hierarchy, but is there a way I can derive or learn the categorization?) Is that statistically valid?
The source geographical data is in admin units (town boundary multi-polygons). I'm thinking either option (a) convert everything into a 100km2 grid, or (b) cos(lat).cos(lon), cos(lat).sin(lon), sin(lat) of shape centroid lon/lat, to get (scaled) coordinates in 3D, plus area. Option (b) is easier, except admin units change over time so I'd have to re-allocate older figures to the latest boundaries.
(I will also add location metadata such as country, population, season timeseries, etc.)
Any recommendations/hunches? Or just start with univariate and build?
I am (perhaps naively) considering ARIMA, XGBoost, LSTM, a timeseries transformer, maybe Mamba, if relevant. Given my utter inexperience, I suspect XGBoost is probably the sweet spot of complexity/capability and novice hyperparameter tuning skills, although I'll try more complex architectures, as I understand trees will miss interplay between production and price, which is important here.
Huge thanks for any tips at all.
